# How to install a jekyll plugin for an octopress blog?

Tags: jekyll, octopress

I have recently found excellent Octopress & Jekyll frameworks, and I am going
to switch my homepage to octopress from wordpress (which is rather well documented).
However, I am eager to add several plugins to octopress. For example, the one that
generates bibliographies. There are several plugins for Jekyll for doing this
(for example, https://github.com/inukshuk/jekyll-scholar)

However, I was not able to make it functional for an octopress website;
I tried to follow the install instructions, and instead of jekyll plugin directory
use the octopress plugin directory; it did not work out.

Can anyone provide me with general instructions how the jekyll plugin should be installed for a simple octopress blog (an example for jekyll-scholar would be enough).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not 100% sure, as I'm new to Octopress and Jekyll myself but here goes:

## Install

---

```
$ [sudo] gem install jekyll-scholar
```

## Usage

---

Create a file called `ext.rb` in the `plugins` directory of Octopress.

The contents of the `ext.rb` file should be

```
require 'jekyll/scholar'
```

To adjust the Jekyll-Scholar settings, use the configuration file `_config.yml`